# Spacing above and below equation

Tags: spacing, equations

In my thesis I use a lots of equation-enviroments, but not only for equations itself.
I use it to emphasize things from the text.
But I have the feeling that the space above and below is too much.
I did not change any options for this, but is it normal that there is so much space, like in the following code?

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12 ,BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
    We will use the following very often.
    As the set of naturals numbers we have
    \begin{equation*}
        \mathbb N 
        = 
        \left\{ 
        1,2,\dots
        \right\}.
    \end{equation*}
    To note that two elements $a$ and $b$ are equivalent modulo an integer $n$ we will write
\begin{equation*}
    a \equiv b \pmod n.
\end{equation*}
    If we want to note the remainder of $a$ divided by $n$ we will write
\begin{equation*}
    \left({a\bmod n}\right).
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The output is
[image]

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Just wondering: is "befaboveore" a typo? If not: what shall it mean? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, I edited the title.

Comment: Looks perfectly normal to me. I don't think that squeezing the lines would make the result any better.

Comment: Agree. Please keep in mind that LaTeX is no MS Word or similar in disguise, but tries to arrange optimal at any compile from a typesetting perspective. This includes, e.g., legibility, typestting conventions etc.

Comment: Off topic: Since you're using `amsmath`, you can use `\[ ,,, \]` instead of `equation*` to get an unnumbered equation.  (Doesn't change the spacing.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted, adjusting the vertical space may not be a good idea, but if you really must you can use a negative [vspace](/questions/tagged/vspace) value, such as the following.

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12 ,BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
    We will use the following very often.
    As the set of naturals numbers we have

    \vspace{-5ex}

    \begin{equation*}
        \mathbb N 
        = 
        \left\{ 
        1,2,\dots
        \right\}.
    \end{equation*}

    To note that two elements $a$ and $b$ are equivalent modulo an integer $n$ we will write

    \vspace{-5ex}

\begin{equation*}
    a \equiv b \pmod n.
\end{equation*}

    If we want to note the remainder of $a$ divided by $n$ we will write

    \vspace{-5ex}

\begin{equation*}
    \left({a\bmod n}\right).
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No sorry this is completely wrong, never have a blank line before a displayed equation, this is forcing an extra all white paragraph of spurious space and then compensating with negative space. You can adjust `\abovedisplayskip` if you want to adjust the spacce above a diplay.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of taste and conventions.

You can set a different spacing (here half of the standard), if you so prefer:

```
\documentclass[
%  ngerman,
  fontsize=11pt,
  DIV=12,
  BCOR = 10mm,
  parskip=half-,
  twoside,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for mock text

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\skipeval{\abovedisplayskip/2}}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\skipeval{\belowdisplayskip/2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

We will use the following very often.
As the set of naturals numbers we have
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbb{N} = \{1,2,\dotsc\}.
\end{equation*}
To note that two elements $a$ and $b$ are equivalent modulo an integer $n$ we will write
\begin{equation*}
  a \equiv b \pmod{n}.
\end{equation*}
If we want to note the remainder of $a$ divided by $n$ we will write
\begin{equation*}
  ({a\bmod n}).
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the result *without* `parskip` and the adjustment:

[image]

Maybe you judge that the space is excessive. But I'd like to notice that with `parskip` your readers will *not* be able to distinguish whether a new paragraph starts after the first or second displays.

What happens if you have a paragraph starting with your setup (and the reduced vertical spacing? Here it is:

[image]

Without `parskip`, you'd get the same vertical spacing as in the second picture and the paragraph indentation.

Points to note: `\mathbb N` is wrong and should be `\mathbb{N}`; `\left` and `\right` in the places where you use them just add unwanted horizontal space; `\dotsc` is the right command for ellipsis after a comma without another comma following.